# Shiny + Prism + Platform Service Example

Tags: xamarin, prism

I am attempting to update a Prism 8.1 app to use Shiny v2.
In trying to turn one of my services into a Job I keep getting a container resolution error (using Unity). I am not sure what the pattern is for registering platform implementations of services. The Job has a service that is from my platform project but at the time the `services.RegisterJob()` is called I guess the platform initializer has not run.

Can someone post an example of how you are supposed to register platform implementations with Shiny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the intended design but I solved the platform services this way.

I added a constructor parameter to my `ShinyStartup` like this:

```
public Startup(IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer) : base(PrismContainerExtension.Current)
{
    _platformInitializer = platformInitializer;
}
```

and then in my `AppDelegate` I used this:
`Shiny.ShinyHost.Init(new Shiny.ApplePlatform(), new Startup(new iOSInitializer()));`

Where `iOSInitializer` is my Prism `IPlatformInitializer`.

Then in `Startup` I added:

```
protected override void RegisterServices(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    _platformInitializer.RegisterTypes(containerRegistry);
    ...
}
```

As far as the `IJob` not resolving dependencies when using `RegisterJob`, I moved job registration to `App.OnStart` using `IJobManager.Register` and it works. Also not sure if this is the intended design.

I did all my container wire up before calling `RegisterJob` and it still failed to resolve so there must be something under the covers that is happening in the Prism+Shiny world.